# How to map string[] into java List<String> with DataClassRowMapper in JDBC with Postgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a DB made with PosthreSql. I need to query for a object that has 1 column as a array. Is there a way for me to use DataClassRowMapper to map postgresql Array into Java List? Or do i have the create custom mapper for that? The Java Record itself will be useed as a REST response for the client side.

Code example:

```
select t1.uuid, t1.name, array_agg(t2.a_uuid) a_uuids
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.uuid = t2.b_uuid
group by t1.uuid, t1.name
```

Java code example

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("""query""", params, DataClassRowMapper.newInstance(Result.class));
```

Where Result is

```
public record Record(UUID uuid, String name, List<UUID> aUuids);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?!

Comment: @YCF_L added code example. Exact query just changed table and column names. table2 is a mapping table between 2 tables.

Comment: I mean your java code

Comment: @YCF_L added java code